# Invalid value error during converting string to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion, data-science

I have a data set and there is a feature which containing numbers in string like

```
"153", "45", "13", "345"
```

I'd like to convert these values to integer with python and i wrote this line of code:

```
df.column = df.column.astype("int")
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,83E+05'
```

There is some value like:

```
3.89E+05, 2.60E+05, 3,13E+05
```

How can i convert it to any numerical data type?
Thanks in advance

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem isn't the scientific notation per se, but the fact that they are float values AND they're in scientific notation.  I found that this works as a one line solution:

```
df.column.astype('float64').astype('int64')
```

If your string values are in European convention, you can add the following line as well to put in a pandas-friendly format.

```
df.column = df.apply(lambda x: str(x.column).replace(',','.'), axis=1)
df.column.astype('float64').astype('int64')
```

Comment: it says 'could not convert string to float: '2,83E+05' ' I actually tried a thing that similar to that.

Comment: See the update, should work with your number conventions

Comment: I dropped all NA values but there is still "Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer" error.

Comment: You can filter infinite values (or NA, or other specific) with numpy:  df = df.column.replace({numpy.inf:0, numpy.nan:0})